# Getting the right node for query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, nodes

I am having a problem getting the correct nodes for my query. Can I ask if there is resource in writing XML.value queries?

For example I have this XML below. (Note I am not putting full code).

```
<Result>
  <TestCaseCollection>
    <TestCase name="PowerUPDUT" isPass="true" totalTime="7095.7095">
      <Result name="TestSoftwareID" type="Text" unit="" value="TX1431-002" limitType="Equals" limit="TX1431-002" isPass="true" />
    </TestCase>
    <TestCase name="ReadTestData" isPass="false" totalTime="60120.0114">
      <Result name="Send Radio Enable command" type="Text" unit="" value="" isPass="false">
        <Error code="EER10101002" message="Failed to write value to FG for SetCAMCommand: R;1;RADIO-EN">
          <Exception level="0">
            <Message>EER10101002-Failed to write value to FG for SetCAMCommand: R;1;RADIO-EN</Message>
            <StackTrace>   at TAF.Device.NewportDUT.OnSetMTModemCmd(Text MTModemCmd)
   at TAF.Parameter.WriteAttribute`1.set_Value(MeasurableType value)
   at TAF.Step.AssignStep`1.OnExecute()
   at TAF.Step.Step.Execute()</StackTrace>
            <Source>NewportDUT</Source>
            <TargetSite>Void OnSetMTModemCmd(TAF.Measurable.Text)</TargetSite>
          </Exception>
        </Error>
      </Result>
    </TestCase>
    <TestCase name="TraceabilityCheck" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="FirmwareUpgradeConfirmation" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="UploadCAMFirmware" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="UploadCambridgeFw" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="PreTestCheck" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="CAM Configuration" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="ShippingStates" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="ECO Data Fetching" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="LED Test" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="SaveECOData" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
  </TestCaseCollection>
</Result>
```

I tried using this code to get Error Code, Error message and TestCase name of the isPass = failed TestCase.

```
,[ResultXML].value('(/Results/TestCaseCollection/TestCase[@isPass="false"]/Result[@isPass="false"]/Error)[1]/@code', 'varchar(max)') As "ErrorCode"
,[ResultXML].value('(/Results/TestCaseCollection/TestCase[@isPass="false"])[1]/@name', 'varchar(max)') As "ErrorType"
,[ResultXML].value('(/Results/TestCaseCollection/TestCase[@isPass="false"]/Result[@isPass="false"]/Error)[1]/@message', 'varchar(max)') As "ErrorMessage"
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong and also if there are resource on how to write these properly.

Comment: In the given code, you have used the <Result> tag. While when fetching the values you are using "Results" in your code. I think it should be "Result"                                             ```[ResultXML].value('(/Result/TestCaseCollection/TestCase[@isPass="false"]/Result[@isPass="false"]/Error)[1]/@code', 'varchar(max)') As "ErrorCode"```

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expressions were off. Please try the following test case.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<Result>
  <TestCaseCollection>
    <TestCase name="PowerUPDUT" isPass="true" totalTime="7095.7095">
      <Result name="TestSoftwareID" type="Text" unit="" value="TX1431-002" limitType="Equals" limit="TX1431-002" isPass="true" />
    </TestCase>
    <TestCase name="ReadTestData" isPass="false" totalTime="60120.0114">
      <Result name="Send Radio Enable command" type="Text" unit="" value="" isPass="false">
        <Error code="EER10101002" message="Failed to write value to FG for SetCAMCommand: R;1;RADIO-EN">
          <Exception level="0">
            <Message>EER10101002-Failed to write value to FG for SetCAMCommand: R;1;RADIO-EN</Message>
            <StackTrace>   at TAF.Device.NewportDUT.OnSetMTModemCmd(Text MTModemCmd)
   at TAF.Parameter.WriteAttribute`1.set_Value(MeasurableType value)
   at TAF.Step.AssignStep`1.OnExecute()
   at TAF.Step.Step.Execute()</StackTrace>
            <Source>NewportDUT</Source>
            <TargetSite>Void OnSetMTModemCmd(TAF.Measurable.Text)</TargetSite>
          </Exception>
        </Error>
      </Result>
    </TestCase>
    <TestCase name="TraceabilityCheck" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="FirmwareUpgradeConfirmation" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="UploadCAMFirmware" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="UploadCambridgeFw" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="PreTestCheck" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="CAM Configuration" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="ShippingStates" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="ECO Data Fetching" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="LED Test" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
    <TestCase name="SaveECOData" isPass="true" totalTime="0" />
  </TestCaseCollection>
</Result>';

SELECT col.value('(Result[@isPass="false"]/Error)[1]/@code', 'varchar(max)') As "ErrorCode"
    ,col.value('@name', 'varchar(max)') As "ErrorType"
    ,col.value('(Result[@isPass="false"]/Error)[1]/@message', 'varchar(max)') As "ErrorMessage"
FROM @xml.nodes('/Result/TestCaseCollection/TestCase[@isPass="false"]') AS tab(col);
```